# JPype with Java 10

Tags: java, python, java-10, jpype

Does anybody know, if JPype works with a Java 10 JRE?
I have tested JPype with Java 8 without any problems but I am not able to use it in combination with Java 10.

My test setup:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Python 3.5.2 (Anaconda 4.2.0) 64-bit
- Spyder 3.3.0
- JPype 0.6.3 (via `pip install`)

I execute my Python test script in Spyder (included in Anaconda package).

Test using Java 8 (jre1.8.0_181) succeeded.
JPype JVM starts without any problems.

Test using Java 10 (jre-10.0.2) fails with this error:

```
RuntimeError: Unable to load DLL [C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.2\bin\server\jvm.dll], error = Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
 at native\common\include\jp_platform_win32.h:58
```

I do have a german Windows version, so the part "Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden" may be translated as something like "The specified module cannot be found".

I used this Python code, to start the JVM in JPype:

```
import jpype

java_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre-10.0.2\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll"
jpype.startJVM(java_path, '-ea')
```

**Edit: Adding the whole test script**

```
import jpype
import os

java_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre-10.0.2\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll"
# java_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_181\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll"

# print exists result to be sure the file exists
print(os.path.exists(java_path))

jpype.startJVM(java_path, '-ea')

print("it works")
```

If I use the Java 10 part, it does not work but if I use the Java 8 part (currently commented), it does work.
The first `print` command prints `True` in both cases.

Thank you in advance,
Markus

Comment: First thing, I would have checked would be if the `jvm.dll` that you are addressing is present in the location or not.  Next, can you show the code that actually results in the `RuntimeError` as mentioned in *"Test using Java 10 (jre-10.0.2) fails with this error"*?

Comment: The file definitely exists at this location. I have copy&pasted the path from the file system into the test script and double-checked its location.
The 3 lines code which I've posted in my question was the test which leads to this error.

Comment: Is JPype 32-bit by any chance? I'm just wondering if a 32-bit app is trying to load a 64-bit jvm.dll.

Comment: Both Java RE, 8 and 10, which I have used in my tests, are 64-bit. JPype works well with the Java 8 64-bit RE but doesn't work if I use the Java 10 64-bit RE.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using JDK 10.0.2 and jpype 0.6.3 works fine. As mentioned in the [jpype documentation](https://jpype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), the installation looks for a JVM at the path mentioned in `JAVA_HOME` system variable.

```
>>> from jpype import *
>>> getDefaultJVMPath()
'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-10.0.2\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll'
```

And my `JAVA_HOME` points to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2' which is why it is [recommended in using-jpype](https://jpype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#using-jpype) that you start JVM this way -

```
startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath(), "-ea")
```